# Nonincreasing derivative implies nondecreasing function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

Suppose $f\colon[0,\infty)\to[0,\infty)$ is differentiable with continuous derivative such that its derivative $f'$ is nonincreasing. Does this imply that $f$ is non-decreasing?.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. If $f'(x)\lt0$ for some $x\geqslant0$, then $f'(y)\leqslant -c$ for every $y\geqslant x$, with $c\gt0$. The [mean value theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem) yields $f(y)\leqslant f(x)+cx-cy$ for every $y\geqslant x$. Since $f(x)+cx-cy\to-\infty$ when $y\to+\infty$, this contradicts the assumption that $f\geqslant0$ everywhere. Thus, $f'(x)\geqslant0$ for every $x\geqslant0$, in particular $f$ is nondecreasing.

Comment: The continuity of $f'$ is not needed.

Comment: I think I see what you mean: you use that $f$ is differentiable at $y$, so by considering the difference quotient, $\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=f'(y)\le-c$.

Comment: @Didier how do you get $f(y)\leqslant f(x)+cx-cy$,mean value theory can not get it.the defination of quotient also can not get it.because $x$ in$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=f'(y)\le-c $is not the first given $x$.

Comment: @TaoHong洪涛 `mean value theory can not get it`... ??